# reading a file into array list in scala spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am completely new to spark and scala.

I want to read a file into an array list.

This is how its done in java.

```
List<String> sourceRecords;
sourceRecords = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader SW;
SW = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(srcpath[0].toString()));
String srcline ;
while ((srcline = SW.readLine()) != null)  {
sourceRecords.add(srcline.toString());
}
```

How to do it in scala in spark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very easy. For example,

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("your_file_path")
val sourceRecords = rdd.toArray
```

However, you don't need to convert `rdd` to `Array`. You can manipulate `rdd` like an `Array`.

You can find more information in https://spark.incubator.apache.org/examples.html

Comment: Docs for Scala, or for Spark?

Comment: For Scala, I recommend this book: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Scala-Comprehensive-Step-Step/dp/0981531644 . For Spark, I recommend this book : http://www.packtpub.com/fast-data-processing-with-spark/book

Comment: Thanx. I need to convert a map reduce code into scala. I have seen the map function in scala. But i dont understand it. like in wordcount   
     val file = spark.textFile("hdfs://...")
    val counts = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    .map(word => (word, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...")

But my mapper in mapreduce has a complex algorithm. how can i implement it in scala.

Comment: If you have no time to learn Scala, you can use Spark Java APIs.

Comment: Can u tell how does the map function for spark java work. like in hadoop map function is called once for each line of file. is it the same way it works in spark

Comment: It's similar. Hadoop MapReduce is like `map` and `groupByKey` in Spark. However, Spark is more powerful as it supports more operators.